# Exporting a list of projects in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, node.js, react.js

I am using the following code in a Node.js / React project. It works fine but it looks like it could be consolidated a little more using a OO pattern.

```
import projectsData from '../data/index.js';

function Project(project) {
  this.name = project.name;
  this.order = project.order;
  this.title = project.title;
  this.date = project.date;
  this.tags = project.tags;
  this.logo = project.logo;
  this.html = project.html;
  this.agency = project.agency;
  this.slides = Object.values(project.slides).map(slide => slide);
  this.path = `projects/${this.name}`;
  this.route = `/projects/${this.name}`;
  this.slidesPath = `/projects/${this.name}/slides/`;
  this.hiDefAffix = '@2x';
};

const all = {};
Object.values(projectsData).map(project => all[project.name] = new Project(project));

const projects = {
  all,
  sorted(){ return Object.values(this.all).sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order) },
  get(project) {
    try {
      if (this.all[project]){
        return this.all[project];
      } else {
        throw new Error(`Project "${project}" not found.`);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return false;
    }
  },
  toJSON() {
    return JSON.stringify(this.all);
  }
};

export default projects;
```

Basically I have a constructor and an exported object that ends up having a bunch of objects created by the constructor above it. Can these be consolidated in some way?

Comment: What's that `throw` about, why not just `return false` directly?

Comment: `.map(slide => slide)` doesn't change anything, it should be omitted

Comment: `toJSON` should, despite the name, not return a JSON string but rather an object that will be used for the result when calling `JSON.stringify(projects)`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "more object-oriented"?

Comment: @bergi Here's my reasoning: 
re: "throw" it's because I wanted to see where the program failed without breaking it

re:  don't use .map(slide => slide). You're right, that is unnecessary. Thanks! 

re: toJSON. If that's the case then toJSON is the same thing as "all". If you were working on this project which of those names would you prefer?

Comment: And by more OO I was thinking that the constructor above could be grouped together in the projects object somehow, but couldn't reason how to make it combined. And also the "all" variable above seems to stick out, that looks like it could also be combined into the projects object.

Comment: Ah, I'd just use a breakpoint to see fails, instead of halting on any exceptions. Regarding `toJSON`, I don't know how this object is supposed to be used (other than being stringified?), so I can't tell. Having both a property and a getter method is fine.

Comment: No, the `Project` constructor should not be part of the `projects` object. But you might want to put it in an extra module and only import it, for better separation of concerns. The `all` and even the `projects` variables can be avoided, yes, but there's nothing wrong with them - they're part of the internal implementation of the module, and it doesn't matter at all how the export is constructed and filled.

Comment: @Bergi great!  I've removed the toJSON function, moved the Project constructor to another file, and left the all object because it's nice to be able to do projects.all().map ...etc...  thanks so much for your insight.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Project(project) {
  this.name = project.name;
  this.order = project.order;
  this.title = project.title;
  this.date = project.date;
  this.tags = project.tags;
  this.logo = project.logo;
  this.html = project.html;
  this.agency = project.agency;
  this.slides = Object.values(project.slides).map(slide => slide);
  this.path = `projects/${this.name}`;
  this.route = `/projects/${this.name}`;
  this.slidesPath = `/projects/${this.name}/slides/`;
  this.hiDefAffix = '@2x';
};
```

If all this does is just set props to an instance, then you probably don't even need a constructor. You can simply use a factory function that accepts a project object and returns an object with properties.

```
function createProject({name, order, title, date, tags, logo, html, agency, slides, name}){
  return {
    name,
    order,
    title,
    date,
    tags,
    logo,
    html,
    agency,
    slides: Object.values(project.slides),
    path: `projects/${this.name}`,
    route: `/projects/${this.name}`,
    slidesPath: `/projects/${this.name}/slides/`,
    hiDefAffix: '@2x'
  };
}
```

---

```
Object.values(project.slides).map(slide => slide);
```

Looks like `project.slides` is an object. `Object.values` creates an array of values. `array.map` just creates a copy of that array, which is useless.

---

```
const all = {};
Object.values(projectsData).map(project => all[project.name] = new Project(project));
```

You are misusing `array.map`. `array.map` is for transforming one array into another in a 1-to-1 transformation. What you are doing here is creating an object. This is a job for `array.reduce`.

```
const all = Object.values(projectsData).reduce((all, project) => {
  return { ...all, [project.name]: createProject(project)};
}, {});
```

---

```
try {
  if (this.all[project]){
    return this.all[project];
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Project "${project}" not found.`);
  }
} catch (error) {
  return false;
}
```

The `try-catch` is pointless. You are immediately catching the error and simply returning false. Why not return false in the first place?

```
return this.all[project] || false;
```

---

```
toJSON() {
  return JSON.stringify(this.all);
}
```

I believe this is a practice commonly done by Java developers to have an intermediate function to handle special properties. But this is unnecessary in most cases since any simple JS object is immediately serializable by `JSON.stringify`, and you don't appear to use any of the new data types.

---

> How can I make this Javascript code more OO

This is the wrong way to think in terms of programming, locking yourself to a paradigm. What you should be asking is *"How to make this code simpler?"* or *"How to make this code easier to understand?"*.

Also, OO isn't about classes, or constructors or methods and properties. It's about *working with objects*, whether they are instances of classes or simple data structures like object literals or arrays. You can do a lot with just object literals and arrays. You aren't going to need the class and methods fluff in most cases.